# C++ - Hard Time With Polymorphism And Dynamic Casting

Tags: c++, casting, architecture, polymorphism, game-engine

I'm trying to design an file system for a personal game engine I'm working on and I have a hard time using polymorphism while avoiding dynamic casting.

### Problem

I have different kind of objects in my game engine (e.g., `Texture`, `Mesh`, etc.) which all inherits from the class `Object`.

```cpp
class Object
{
};

class Texture : public Object
{
};
```

I have the concept of files which holds an object.

```cpp
class File
{
public:
    Object* GetObject() const { return m_Object; }

private:
    Object* m_Object;
};
```

I want to be able to define a command for a file holding a specific type of object, hence the class `FileCommand`.

```cpp
class FileCommand
{
public:
    virtual void Execute(File* file) = 0;
};
```

Now, let's say we have a class called `OpenFileInTextureEditorCommand` which inherits from `FileCommand`. This class should obviously expect to receive a file containing a texture. But, to ensure that, we have to cast the return value of `file.GetObject()`, which is of type `Object*`, to `Texture*`.

```cpp
class OpenFileInTextureEditorCommand : public FileCommand
{
public:
    void Execute(File* file) override
    {
        Texture* texture = std::dynamic_cast<Texture*>(file->GetObject());
        if (texture)
        {
            // Open texture in texture editor...
        }
    }
};
```

### Solution

The best I've been able to achieve with my designs is to camouflage the dynamic casting.

So, let's re-use the class `Object` and the class `Texture`

Now, I've transformed the class `File` into a templated class. Since files needs to be stored in a `std::vector`, I'm forced to create a non-templated base class `FileBase`. The purpose of `File` is mainly to handle dynamic casting.

```cpp
class FileBase
{
public:
    Object* GetObject() const { return m_Object; }

protected:
    Object* m_Object = nullptr;
};

template<class T>
class File : protected FileBase
{
public:
    // Turns the class into an abstract class -- cannot be instanciated. Its only job to handle dynamic casting.
    virtual ~File<T>() = default;

    T* GetObject() const
    {
        // Camouflaged dynamic casting
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(m_Object);
    }
};
```

Since my goal is to avoid dynamic casting in my `FileCommand` implementations, I've also transformed it into a templated class. Since `FileCommand` also needs to be stored in a `std::vector`, I'm forced to create a non-templated base class `FileCommandBase`. As with `File`, the purpose of `FileCommand` is mainly to handle dynamic casting.

```cpp
class FileCommandBase
{
public:
    virtual void Execute(FileBase* file) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class FileCommand : protected FileCommandBase
{
public:
    // Turns the class into an abstract class -- cannot be instanciated. Tts only job is to handle dynamic casting.
    virtual void Execute(File<T>* file) = 0;

protected:
    void Execute(FileBase* file) override
    {
        // Camouflaged dynamic casting
        Execute(dynamic_cast<File<T>*>(file));
    }
};
```

Finally, we can implement `OpenFileInTextureEditorCommand`, which doesn't require the dynamic casting anymore.

```cpp
class OpenFileInTextureEditorCommand : public FileCommand<Texture>
{
public:
    void Execute(File<Texture>* file) override
    {
        Texture* texture = file.GetObject();
        if (texture)
        {
            // Open texture in texture editor...
        }
    }
};
```

### Conclusion

The code of `OpenFileInTextureEditorCommand` in itself isn't really shorter, but I think it's cleaner.

Although, while writing this post, I've come to some conclusions:

- More dynamic casting than before, except it's implicit in some way
- More classes than before, may be harder to maintain

Now, I may be too persistent on trying to avoid to do dynamic casting, but I see people talking about how the presence of dynamic casting is an indicator of a bad design.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: In your grand design, why is a `File` not an `Object`? It seems like you want "everything is an object" kind of thing in every other aspect.

Comment: I wouldn't place the emphasis on File, it isn't important and what if you get resources from elsewhere like in an aggregate file or downloaded? I prefer a ResourceManager that serves as a factory for resources. Don't care where they came from, I just want to be able to request the resource and get that object back.

Comment: Unfortunately, your request for "opinion and experiences" does not appear to be appropriate for Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is a question/answer site, with answers based on facts and citations. I could venture one possible suggestion that uses polymorphism, and someone else might argue that this is an appropriate use for dynamic_cast. There is no authoritative answer here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Simply because they're two different things in my design. `Object` is the base class for my engine objects, while `File` holds the data, the `Object` instance, and may contain information on where the actual file is stored on the operating system, it's name, it's size, etc.

Now, I didn't want to be forced to make my engine objects inherit from `File` if I want them to be an engine object, but also stored in a file somewhere. That's why I use composition over inheritance here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The terminology isn't final of course. In my actual code, I'm using the term *asset*, which is closer to *resource*. But, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry about that. Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion:

- First, `dynamic_cast` is a keyword instead of a method, so `std` is not needed.
- Second, if the `Object` itself isn't virtual, `static_cast` is enough.
- Third, we say "dynamic casting is an indicator of bad design" because you may abstract them as a common class with all necessary methods to show their properties so that polymorphism will handle them. However, `Object` is too high-level, too abstract, that it will obviously hide many unique characteristics of the object and it's hard to perform polymorphism suitably. So in that case, i.e. you have some very general classes, and you rely on them heavily, dynamic casting is totally acceptable. This is a usual case in more OOP languages, e.g. in C#, it's called **boxing** and **unboxing** to represent cast to `object` or vice versa.
- Finally, `dynamic_cast` may have a not-bad performance if there is no multiple inheritance; in the best case, it may be only slightly slower than `static_cast`, so it may not be a big concern if you really need it(unless your profiler tells you not...). You can see the analysis in this [blog](https://lancern.xyz/2022/11/04/dynamic-cast-benchmark/).

Comment: The blog you referred to is in chinese, is there an english version?

Comment: @IronFist Sorry, I prefer an English version, but there seems no similar blog in English. This is the only one that I've found to analyze the performance of `dynamic_cast` thoroughly. Sorry and you may use auto-translation :).

Comment: Thanks @o_oTurtle. I've read what I needed to read in your third point. I will also take a look at `static_cast`.